# Teschl Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems equation (6.28)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes

While reading Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems by Gerald Teschl, I found the following statement:

"More Generally, suppose the equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ has a fixed point $x_0$. Then it is not hard to see that $x_0$ is stable if
\begin{eqnarray*}
\dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} \leq 0, \;\;\;\; x \in U(x_0)\setminus\{x_0\}
\end{eqnarray*}
for some neighborhood $U(x_0)$ and assymptotically stable if the inequality is strict."

This makes sense to me, as this expression is related to the derivative of $f$ (and consequently, the second derivative of the solution). As I understand, I am not supposed to calculate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix, but I have to analyse the sign of $f$. Is there a way to show this expression this way?

Comment: You say: 'Is there a way to show this expression this way?' By this way, do you mean using the eigenvalues of the Jacobian on the 1 dimensional problem. The Jacobian takes on a simpler scalar form in such a case. I think this example is given as an easier example to give an intuitive understanding for the more complex techniques that you are familiar with involving the Jacobian. I guess I'm not sure what you are confused about.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, but this comes from the fact that you are working in dimension 1. This can be generalized even locally for systems on a large dimensional space, however instead of a negative derivative, you can require a negative (semi-)definite Jacobian matrix at the equilibrium point. In higher dimension, it just becomes a sufficient condition.